# ZFS defragmentation after snapshot send receive

Tags: zfs

Let's say my ZFS file system is heavily fragmented.

What happens if I "synchronize" this file system with a secondary ZFS file system via ZFS snapshots (send/receive) ?

Will my second ZFS be defragmented ?

Answer (score 5):

It should be defragmented indeed.

The ZFS stream contains data and metadata, but, hopefully, not the layout under which that data is distributed on the source side. ZFS is then free to use the most efficient one when storing the data. Of course, if the receiving pool is already heavily fragmented and the available space is scattered all over the place, some fragmentation might still be present there. There would be no fragmentation if there is enough, contiguous free space, and of course if an ad hoc pool is created for the operation.

Comment: Correct, send/receive streams do not encode placement information (or even replication, compression, or deduping ratios). Everything about how the data is placed must be recreated on the target pool.